Різниця у технічному перекладі "accessibility" та "availability"
Контекст який був у мене в голові:

availability > server availability > доступність сервісу, зокрема в контексті угоди про рівень послуг
accessibility > UX accessibility > доступність інтерфейсу користувача, зокрема в контексті користувачів з проблемами зору/слуху/тощо (тестування вебдоступності)

Стаття, яка викликала сумніви у перекладі цих термінів: 
(Не)доступні сайти державних органів України
Я відразу подумала про availability, але у статті йдеться про accessibility.
Я вважаю, що це неприйнятно - мати таку колізію у перекладах. Але ж виглядає що обидва переклади семантично правильні, і більш-менш усталені (джерел мало, а ті що є - підтверджують гіпотезу).
Google translate також пропонує переклад приступність, правда, для обидвох англійських термінів...
Питання:

Можливо, ви знаєте інші переклади?
Можливо, ви знаєте централізований словник українських технічних термінів?
Можливо, ви не погоджуєтесь що ця колізія неприйнятна, і можете пояснити?


Дуже цікаве зауваження. Буду обережнішим з перекладом цих термінів. Здається основний переклад для availability це наявність. Здається це те, що треба у випадку часу працездатності сервісу.

@Yola дякую, наявність добре звучить як іменник, але я не впевнена щодо заперечного прикметника ненаявний...

Service unavailable (HTTP error 503) - сервіс не доступний. Access denied (HTTP error 403) - доступ заборонено. Тобто, ваш сайт фактично доступний в мережі, сервер відповідає (HTTP 200 OK). Але загальний доступ до інтерфейсу вебсайту обмежений, надається лише для певних груп користувачів.

Коли йдеться про людей з обмеженими можливостями, зокрема, вадами зору, кажемо саме про доступність (accessibility). Тобто інші користувачі можуть отримати доступ без проблем. В заголовку статті помилки немає.

З мого досвіду розробки можу пояснити яка різниця.
Availability - сервіс існує і функціонує, але у вас немає до нього доступу. Акцент на існуванні.
Accessibility - це доступність для прямого користування. Робиться акцент саме на доступність.


Запитниця
Я відразу подумала про availability, але у статті йдеться про accessibility.

Це насправдї цікава мить, оскільки доступність це, схоже, калька якраз на друге.

accessibility (n.)
1758, from French accessibilité (from Late Latin accessibilitas), or else a native formation from accessible + -ity.
↓
accessible (adj.)
c. 1400, "affording access, capable of being approached or reached," from Old French accessible and directly from Late Latin accessibilis, verbal adjective from Latin accessus "a coming near, an approach; an entrance," from accedere "approach, go to, come near, enter upon" (see accede). The meaning "easy to reach" is from 1640s; of art or writing, "able to be readily understood," by 1961 (a word not needed before writing or art often deliberately was made not so).
↓
accede (v.)
"come to or arrive at" (a state, position, office, etc.), early 15c., from Latin accedere "approach, go to, come near, enter upon," from assimilated form of ad "to" (see ad-) + cedere "go, move, withdraw" (from PIE root *ked- "to go, yield"). Latin ad- usually became ac- before "k" sounds.

Де, коротко: ad → ac до + cedere ступати. А оскільки це далеко не єдина латіна → українська калька, то це цїлком усталена пара. Волосне, access якраз так і перекладають як доступ, чого не сказати про avail. Тож маїмо проблему насамперед з гиншим словом, котре примазали до цього, бо ніяк не повʼязане зі словом ступати.

availability (n.)
"capability of advantageous use," 1803, from available + -ity.
↓
available (adj.)
mid-15c., "beneficial," also "valid, effective, capable of producing the desired effect," from avail + -able. The meaning "at one's disposal, capable of being made use of" is recorded from 1827.
↓
avail (v.)
c. 1300, availen, "to help (someone), assist; benefit, be profitable to; be for the advantage of; have force or efficacy, serve for a purpose," apparently an Anglo-French compound of Old French a- "to" (see ad-) + vaill-, present stem of valoir "be worth," from Latin valere "be strong, be worth" (from PIE root *wal- "to be strong").

І з того що бачу, це проблема всіх словянських мов, щонайменше для польської, штокавської, чеської; бо  статтю availability heuristic переклали через слово доступність. Тож можу лише погодитися, що поки мало хто розрізняє ці терміни.

Запитниця
Можливо, ви знаєте централізований словник українських технічних термінів?

Чесно кажучи — нї, але менї відомо про ресурс, що має декілька технічних словників, насамперед це e2u.org.ua. Там переклади для згаданих слів збіжні, що не дивно. Але можна звернути увагу, що для availability декотрі [список нижче] словники надають ще один переклад як придатність, котрого майже не зустрїти до accessibility.

Англійсько-український словник з математики та інформатики 2010 (Є. Мейнарович, М. Кратко)
Великий англо-український словник 2011 (Є.І. Гороть, Л.М. Коцюк, Л.К. Малімон, А.Б. Павлюк.)
Англійсько-український словник-довідник інженерії довкілля 2000 (Тимотей Балабан)

На інших ресурсах і не завжди технічні, але котрі теж так переклали:

Лев В., Вербяний І. Англійсько-український словник
Дейко М. Українсько-англійський та англійсько-український словник широкого вжитку т. 2
Англо-український словник Балла М.І.

Не скажу, що придатність є самодостатнїм замінником, оскільки слово досить навантажете, але якщо є така можливість, то можна його використати.

+1, але майте на увазі, що accessible в контексті документів має конкретне значення: доступність для перегляду людьми з фізичними обмеженнями (зір, слух, моторика).

Дуже дякую за детальну відповідь, "придатний" виглядає як гарна альтернатива!


Microsoft Terminology Search пропонує:

спеціальні можливості


Meta: Деякі корисні онлайн-джерела

З особистого[1] досвіду: багато не-англомовних колег (як-то німці) користуються прямою калькою з англійської. Тобто,

accessible (document) → ексесібл (документ);
read aloud → рід елауд.

Іншими словами, усталених термінів ще нема. Якщо ви працюєте з цією темою, можете придумати і просувати свій варіант. Якщо ж вам треба перекласти одну статтю, можна спробувати обхідний шлях, наприклад:

документ/сайт державної установи, що не сконструйований/відформатований для використання людьми, що мають фізичні обмеження, як-то відповідності до вимог програми автоматичного голосового відтворення, можливості перемикання на висококонтрастну колірну гаму тощо.


[1]: Особиста думка ґрунтується на тривалому досвіді роботи з PDF, в яких значна увага приділяється Accessibility, а державні установи багатьох країн вимагають, щоб усі вхідні-вихідні документи відповідали критеріям, аби проходити Accessibility Check.

Дуже дякую вам за джерела і опис логіки німців!
"Іншими словами, усталених термінів ще нема. Якщо ви працюєте з цією темою, можете придумати і просувати свій варіант."
дякую, підозрювала
Не знаю чи позначати відповідь фінальною, зважаючи що бажану відповідь і так не отримаю, думаю, що поточна - формально відповідає на всі мої питання.

Якщо буде інша відповідь, яка більше відповідатиме саме вашим вимогам, ви завжди зможете перемкнути Accepted Answer.

Чотири роки мешкав у Німеччині, сам (між іншим) accessibility specialist. Принаймні зараз німці використовують barrierefrei/Barrierefreiheit.
